# JButton won't Remove

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Sorry for the newbish question, but I am new to `JStuff`.  I have seen a bunch of different ways to remove a JButton, but none of them seem to be working.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing here, please?

My actionPerformed is being called when I press the button, and my screen is changing like I want it, but the `JButton exit` will not go away

```
JButton exit;

@Override
public void draw() {
    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.setLayout(null);
    exit.setBounds(new Rectangle(SCREEN.getWidth() / 2 + 50, SCREEN
            .getHeight() - 50, SCREEN.getWidth() / 2 - 100, 50));
    exit.setActionCommand("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(exit);
    frame.repaint();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")) {
        frame.remove(exit);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
                    eraseEverythingAndPutSomethingNewUp();
                    System.out.println("This is being called.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling `frame.revalidate` instead of `frame.validate`.  The container may not be marked as invalid and may be ignoring the `validate` request

Comment: @MadProgrammer frame.revalidate() does not compile.  I am using an older version of Java (not by choice). JRE 1.6 I think

Comment: You could try `((JComponent)frame.getContentPane()).revalidate()` instead...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, but no success :(

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Answer (score 3):

In the absences of an [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this example works...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TestFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                final JButton btn = new JButton("Remove");

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(btn);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.remove(btn);
                        ((JComponent)frame.getContentPane()).revalidate();
                        ((JComponent)frame.getContentPane()).repaint();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Might be missing something, but isn't the cast redundant here? [Component#repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) [Component#revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate())

Comment: @Obicere The repaint probably (copied the line), by `revalidate` was only defined in `JComponent` under Java 6, as noted by the OP ;)